# AutoMapper - Very strange behaviour when mapping child lists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

This is most certainly a peculiar issue, and after finding nobody out there with the same issue, I hope I can find someone who actually knows what the problem is.

I've got, say:

```
public class ViewModel
{
     public string TestString { get; set; }
     public ChildObject Child { get; set; }
     public List<Children> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I go to mapping my objects in my controller... i.e.

```
TestObject testObject = Repository.GetObject() // This is my Entity Framework object (with dynamic proxies attached to it)
Mapper.Map(ViewModel, testObject);
```

and, my mappings are defined as:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, TestObjectType>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModelChildView, TestObjectChildType>();
```

Everything maps fine, so I've got my ViewModel setup properly, and my form. The problem though? That's the interesting part.

`ChildObject` is, as the my original objects are, a DynamicProxy (Entity Framework). The `List<Children>` however, gets set to a normal List (even when the original list is a DynamicProxy of `List<Children>`).

This, in turn, means Entity Framework can't access this list as it's not bound to the context properly. I've tried all day to find a workaround with no luck. Any ideas out there?

**Edit**

These are my actual object bindings:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyViewModel, Company>();
 Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyCategoryViewModel, CompanyCategory>(); // I've ever tried removing this line.
 Mapper.CreateMap<List<CompanyCategoryViewModel>, List<CompanyCategory>>();
```

Controller:

```
Mapper.Map(companyViewModel, company);
```

Company object = Dynamic Proxy
CompanyCategories list sub object (of Company), maps, but still not a Dynamic Proxy.

Comment: What is also not clear for me how Entity Framework comes into the picture? Which are the types are the EF entities and which are POCOs?

Comment: Without more inforation, it's going to be hard to know what it is you're trying to do.  Why would ChildObject be a DynamicProxy when you're using a mapped ViewModel?  The whole point of ViewModels is so that you aren't passing entities directly to the view.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been a little more clear. In my "testObject", the original Entity Framework object I'm mapping to, this is where the DynamicProxies are. So, when the ViewModel gets mapped to the "testObject", the non-list items are kept as DynamicProxies - yet the list items aren't.

Comment: Updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Question is not clear for me. Can you provide some more code for 'ChildObject' & 'Children' classes.

Comment: It's really unclear. Do you have DynamicProxyList<Child> or List<DynamicProxyChild>? And your definition, TestObject then TestObjectType, then... Children is same as TestObjectChildType??

Please provide exact ViewModel, exact "Child" and exact TestObject definition. And correct type names in Mapper.CreateMap functions.

Comment: Can you turn off Dynamic Proxies in your context class configuration and check if it works? or are you relying/need the dynamic proxies? I had some issues in this week mapping entities that were returned from the queries as Dynamic Proxies and I just turned them off (since I wasn't really using them)

Comment: Which version of AutoMapper are you using?

Comment: @ahmed - this actually works when DynamicProxies are turned off. However, this isn't ideal as lazy loading stops working on my child entities unfortunately.

Comment: @nemesv - the pre-release version. Tried the latest version and still the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need both the mapping for the `Child` object type and also for the collection. If you have a `List<>` you need to specify `List<>` in your `CreateMap` (it won't work with `IEnumerable`

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, TestObjectType>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModelChildView, TestObjectChildType>();
Mapper.CreateMap<List<ViewModelChildView>>, List<TestObjectChildType>>();
```

Here is a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0e61d1088ac0e6728282) containing my repro code.

To complete the picture I've  used the latest pre-realise version of AutoMapper `2.2.1-ci9004.`

Comment: This actually made a lot of sense. I tried it, but still didn't work - which is sort of thinking it's potentially something wrong with my objects. I'll update my question with what I've got now.

Comment: It should work as it is working in my [Repro code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0e61d1088ac0e6728282). By the way I've also used the latest prerealise version of AutoMapper 2.2.1-ci9004. Please include the complete types in your post: `CompanyViewModel`, `Company`, `CompanyCategoryViewModel`, `CompanyCategory`. Othwevise I am not able to repro your problem and help further to you.

Comment: Through the trouble you've gone to trying to help, I'll award you the bounty here, and look through your repo to see if there's anything I'm missing as it looks to be something peculiar with my objects I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the only difference i think is how you create the maps.

perhaps next to

```
   Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModelChildView, TestObjectChildType>();
```

you should also create a list mapping like

```
   Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<ViewModelChildView>, IEnumerable<TestObjectChildType>>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this already (the first line of the answer is what I'm doing now), with no success :(